Snowflake SQL Compare Clone x Original Counts
I am trying to compare 2 tables (cloned table x original) using Full Outer Join on Snowflake but not getting the results I am expecting:
select 
    'invoice' as TABLE_NAME, 
    to_date(prd.date) as TRANSACTION_DATE,
    count(prd.date) as PROD_COUNT,
  from invoice_latest prd
full outer join
(
    select 
    'invoice_clone' as TABLE_NAME, 
    to_date(date) AS TRANSACTION_DATE,
    count(1) as CLONE_COUNT
    from invoice_latest_clone
    where to_date(date) >= '2024-04-01'
    group by to_date(date)
    order by to_date(date)
) cln
on to_date(prd.date) = cln.TRANSACTION_DATE
where to_date(prd.date) >= '2024-04-02' OR cln.TRANSACTION_DATE is not null
group by to_date(prd.date)
order by to_date(prd.date)

I expect to have NULL for the counts related to the original table for the 1st April but getting the below instead:


It's difficult to comment without having access to your data, but I would create the resultset you want for each table in separate CTEs and then just join the CTEs in your main SELECT (so no GROUP BY etc in the main SELECT). If that doesn't give you the result you expect then it's much easier to debug as you can easily see the data in each CTE. FYI - having a column called "date" (or any other reserved word) is probably not a good design decision

why not using simple comparison like select * from maintable minus select * from clone_table this will show all the differences...

Looks like when the table is cloned there were some data for 4/1. Could be related to your time zone and UTC too.

Can you help us set up data that would give this kind of results?

I see one big problem in the query you shared with us - this query never shows clone_count - where is your query that does that?

The problem is that you are joining and then filtering the results of the join, and then counting.
You should filter first and then do the join.
A query similar to yours that gives similar bad result:
select 'invoice' as table_name
    , o_orderdate as transaction_date
    , count(prd.o_orderdate) as prod_count
    , max(clone_count)
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders prd
full outer join (
    select 'invoice_clone' as table_name
        , o_orderdate as transaction_date
        , count(1) as clone_count
        from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders 
        where o_orderdate >= '1998-07-29'
        group by o_orderdate
        order by o_orderdate        
) cln
on prd.o_orderdate = cln.transaction_date
where o_orderdate >= '1998-07-30' or cln.transaction_date is not null
group by prd.o_orderdate
order by 2


Query fixed:
select 'invoice' as table_name
    , transaction_date
    , count(prd.o_orderdate) as prod_count
    , max(clone_count)
from (
    select *
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders 
    where o_orderdate >= '1998-07-30'
) prd
full outer join (
    select 'invoice_clone' as table_name
        , o_orderdate as transaction_date
        , count(1) as clone_count
        from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.orders 
        where o_orderdate >= '1998-07-29'
        group by o_orderdate
        order by o_orderdate        
) cln
on prd.o_orderdate = cln.transaction_date
where cln.transaction_date is not null
group by transaction_date
order by 2



That makes sense, thank you Felipe Hoffa for your help!
